# Schematic Notation

Tags: power, bus, schematic

I am reading a schematic to find the current leak of my car battery.[image]

What is the dotted line between the top of fuse 6 and 17?

Comment: Usually an optional connection. Maybe it varies by model/year? (I don't see a note indicating such.)  Perhaps an invisible connection (as @KevinWhite noted). At C104 and C11 it also seems to suggest a connector, with the pins assigned as indicated.

Answer (score 0):

I agree it is ambiguous.

Presumably the dotted line just represents an internal connection in the fusebox.

It is unlikely that 30A fuse 8, only feeds fuse 6 (10A). It almost certainly feeds the intermediate bus with multiple loads, each with their own fuse.

Comment: It is the ignition off fuse. It powers everything the car needs while the ignition is in off (alarm, computer checks, clock radio).

Answer (score 0):

Fuse 8 (30A) feeds Fuse 6 (10A), Fuse 17 (10A) and Fuse 19 (20A).  Fuse 9 (40A) is separate.

NCA means No Color Available, which means an internal connection (PCB trace) or an external shield (irrelevant to answer).

From: [Power Distribution (Power and Ground Distribution) - ALLDATA Repair](https://f01.justanswer.com/drhorsefield/6898c6be-eddd-404a-bd5d-ed1e0df6a7b1_TEST1.pdf)
[image]

There is no trace between Fuse 6 and Fuse 17, but one junction going to both.  Fuse 8 comes in, junction to 6 and 17 and trace to 19.

From [daimler-chrysler](http://www.rambodybuilder.com/2004/docs/rs/rswiringdiagram.pdf#page=6) wiring diagram symbols:

[image]

Slight difference in usage, but does support the internal junction.